Can the equation $x^3-2x^2-2x+m=0$ have three different rational solutions?
Background
I was looking at some old Vietnamese Mathematics Olympiad papers and found this one from 1980:
Can the equation $x^3-2x^2-2x+m=0$ have three different rational roots?
My attempt, so far
My first thought was to place restrictions on $m$, so defining $x^3-2x^2-2x+m=0$ and solving $f'(x)=0$ gives turning points at $x=\frac{2-\sqrt{10}}{3}$ and $x=\frac{2+\sqrt{10}}{3}$.
Now $0<f(\frac{2-\sqrt{10}}{3})<1$ and $-5<f(\frac{2+\sqrt{10}}{3})<-4$ so I decided that $-4\leq m\leq 0$
Testing $m=-4,-3,-2,-1,0$ gave cubics which never had more than one rational root.
The problem now is that I do not know whether or not $m$ could be a non-integer.
Any ideas how I should continue? (Or have I taken a really poor choice of approaches to begin with?)
Edit
Thanks everyone for the excellent answers. I tried to accept them all but it looks like the site does not allow for that. Maybe it does, I have no idea.
I was emailed a solution from someone who was involved in the IMO in Australia that goes like this (I'm not sure I completely understand it all so I won't post it as an answer):
Assume the roots are $\frac{u}{t},\frac{v}{t},\frac{w}{t}$ where each is a fraction in simplest form.
Then by Vieta's formulas, $u+v+w=2t$ and $uv+uw+vw=-2t$
This means $u^2+v^2+w^2=4t(t+1)$ which is therefore divisible by 8.
Therefore $u,v,w$ must all be even.
$\frac{t}{2}=\frac{-uv-vw-uw}{4}$ is also an integer which means $t$ is even.
But this contradicts the assumption that all the fractions were in simplest form.

If $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $p(x)$ is your polynomial, then $p(x)/(x-r)=x^2+(r-2)x+(r^2-2r-2)$. For this to have rational roots we need the discriminant to be the square of a rational $t^2$. We get $(3r-2)^2-3t^2=40$ (but check). However, the equation $x^2-3y^2=40z^2$ only has $x=y=z=0$ as integer solutions.

The requirement that all three solutions are different makes this invalid unfortunately.

The argument above shows there cannot be three rational solutions, different or otherwise. The condition of being different roots is not really relevant. The derivative of that polynomial doesn't have rational roots. Therefore, the polynomial cannot have multiple rational roots anyway.

Ah... right. Very different to the approach I'm trying at the moment but it looks like it might work.

Two observations: The rational root theorem forces $x$ to be a divisor of $m$. We also know $m$ can not have exactly one $2$ in its prime factorization or else it's irreducible by Eisenstein's criteria.

Do search the site before posting. There is at least this and also in AOPS. ApproachZero is your friend.

That is very interesting. I did search the site. Nothing came up. I put the equation in to the search using LaTeX and found nothing. Any idea what I may have done wrong?

Is $m$ known to be an integer? Your discussion suggests it might be, but you didn't state it explicitly.
Anyway, if $m$ is an integer, then the rational root theorem tells that all the zeros, call them $a,b,c$, must also be integers, whence
$$
f(x)=x^3-2x^2-2x+m=(x-a)(a-b)(x-c).\qquad(*)
$$
If $m$ is odd, then your cubic is congruent to
$$f(x)\equiv x^3+1\equiv (x+1)(x^2+x+1)\pmod2,$$
but the factor $x^2+x+1$ is odd whenever $x\in\{a,b,c\}$, so this is incompatible with $(*)$. Therefore $m$ must be even, and
$$f(x)\equiv x^3\pmod2,$$
implying that all of $a,b,c$ must be even as well.
But if all of $a,b,c$ are even, then a comparison of the coefficients of the linear terms of $f(x)$
$$
(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3-[a+b+c]x^2+[ab+ac+bc]x-abc
$$
gives a contradiction, because $4\mid [ab+ac+bc]$ but $4\nmid -2$.

I didn't assume $m$ had to be an integer, but I figured from the rational root theorem that it had to be.

I was sent an email today from an ex-colleague. I've transcribed their answer as an edit above. It looks like a nice solution but I can't make all the logical connections immediately.

Suppose $r$ is one rational root of $P(x) = x^3 - 2 x^2 - 2 x + m$.
Thus $m = -r^3 + 2 r^2 + 2 r$.  Now you want
$$ \frac{P(x)}{x-r} = x^2 + (r-2) x + r^2 - 2 r  - 2$$
to have two rational roots.  The roots of this quadratic are
$$ 1 - \frac{r}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{12 + 4 r - 3 r^2}}{2} $$
so for these to be rational, you need $12 + 4 r - 3 r^2$ to be the square of a rational number, thus
$$ 12 + 4 r - 3 r^2 = s^2 $$
must have solutions where $r$ and $s$ are rational.  Completing the square, this can be written as
$$ -3 \left(r - \frac{2}{3}\right)^2 + \frac{40}{3} = s^2 $$
Multiplying by $3$ and letting $t = r - 2/3$, that says
$$ -3 s^2 -9 t^2 + 40 = 0$$
Slightly more generally, we can ask whether $-3 s^2 - 9 t^2 + 40 u^2 = 0$ has rational solutions other than $(0,0,0)$. Getting rid of the squares $9$ and $4$ by taking $T = 3 t$ and $U = 2 u$, we ask whether
$-3 s^2 - T^2 + 10 U^2 = 0$ has rational solutions other than $(0,0,0)$.
There is a theorem of Legendre that lets us answer this:
The equation $a x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2 = 0$, where $a,b,c$ are nonzero integers, pairwise coprime, has rational solutions other than $(0,0,0)$ if and only if $a,b,c$ don't all have the same sign and $-bc$, $-ac$ and $-ab$ are quadratic residues mod $a, b, c$ respectively.
In our case, $-(-3)(-1) = -3$ is not a quadratic residue mod $10$, so the answer is no: $-3 s^2 - T^2 + 10 U^2 = 0$ has no rational solutions other than $(0,0,0)$, and so it is impossible for $P(x)$ to have three rational roots.

Very nice. Is it possible without Legendre's theorem though? Or, alternatively, is that a theorem olympiad students would commonly learn?

@RedFive Olympiad students could verify this instance quickly by brute force. No square of an integer ends with the digit $7$ is something you can expect them to spot.

By Vieta's formulas
$x+y+z=2\tag1$
$x^2+y^2+z^2=8\tag2$
where $x,y,z$ are the roots of the OP's cubic equation $x^3-2x^2-2x+m=0$. Subing $(1)$ in $(2)$ gives
$3u^2+v^2=10\tag3$
where $u=x+\frac12y-1$ and $v=\frac32y-1.$ The same equation is found by Robert.
Our claim is that $(3)$ has no rational solutions. Let $u=\frac ac$, $v=\frac bc$ be reduced forms of $u$ and $v$. Then, our claim is that
$3a^2+b^2=10c^2\tag4$
where $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$, has no integer solutions. If $a,b$ are even then $c$ is even with contradiction. If $a,b$ are odd, then $c^2\equiv 2\pmod8$ with contradiction.

Nice use of gcd. Works well.

The discriminant of the cubic eqution$$x^3-2x^2-2x+m=0$$ being
$$\Delta=-27 m^2+104 m+48$$  in order to have three real and different roots, we must have
$$\frac{4}{27} \left(13-5 \sqrt{10}\right)~ <~ m ~ < ~ \frac{4}{27} \left(13+5 \sqrt{10}\right)$$ which a quite narrow range.
Using the trigonometric solutions, the three real roots are given by
$$x_k=\frac{2}{3} \left(1+\sqrt{10} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3}
   \left(2 \pi  k-\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{52-27 m}{20
   \sqrt{10}}\right)\right)\right)\right) \qquad k=0,1,2$$
There are really many irrational numbers here.

Thanks - I thought about the cubic discriminant but decided it would not help much as I am looking for rational and different roots. My instinct is that there are no values of $m$ for which there are three different, rational roots, but I could be wrong and my attempt (above) and others since to prove this have not worked as yet.
